# primefaces reverse the columns display order

Tags: primefaces

I have to create 2 columns with Primefaces and for this I wrote this code:

```
<div class="ui-fluid">
    <p:panelGrid 
        columns="2"
        columnClasses="
            ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-l-6 ui-lg-3, 
            ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-l-6 ui-lg-9" 
        layout="grid" 
        styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank ui-fluid ">

        <h:outputLabel>
            Column 1 content
        </h:outputLabel>

        <h:outputLabel>
            Column 2 content
       </h:outputLabel>
    </p:panelGrid> 
</div>
```

this work fine if i want to have column 1 above the column 2 in the application. My issue is to display the right column on top and the left column bottom. 
I didn't find how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something from bootstrap :

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
      .order-md-first {
        -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 0;
        -ms-flex-order: -1;
        order: -1;
      }
      .order-md-last {
        -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 14;
        -ms-flex-order: 13;
        order: 13;
      }
      .flex-column-reverse {
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical !important;
        -webkit-box-direction: reverse !important;
        -ms-flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
        flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
      }
  }
```

And i changed the panelGrid by adding those styles :

```
<p:panelGrid 
    columns="2"
     columnClasses="
         ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-l-6 ui-lg-3 order-md-last, 
         ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-l-6 ui-lg-9 order-md-first" 
     layout="grid" 
     styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank ui-fluid ">
```

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same problem with primefaces. Since all modern browsers support flexbox css, it is enough to just use the "order" property. In my code I tend to use the normal Grid CSS from Primefaces but that is just a matter of taste.

Also if you want to change the order responsively, one have to use the classic @media "hack":

XHTML:

```
 <div class="ui-g">
     <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-l-6 ui-lg-3" id="column1">
     </div>
     
     <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-l-6 ui-lg-9" id="column2">
     </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
    /* Primefaces ui-sm*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    #column2 {
        order: 0
    }

    #column1 {
        order: 1
    }
}

/* Primefaces ui-md*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) {
    #mcolumn2 {
        order: 0
    }

    #column1 {
        order: 1
    }
}

/* Primefaces ui-lg*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    #column2 {
        order: 1
    }

    #column1 {
        order: 0
    }
}

/* Primefaces ui-xl and bigger*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px) {
    #column2 {
        order: 1
    }

    #column1 {
        order: 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I'm working with primevue and primeflex but putting my answer here as it was the top google result and also got me going in the right direction.*

Looking at the primeflex css for the [`.flex-order-x`](https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/order) classes, they do it in the way shown above. By using `order: x !important` with `@media` queries for display size modifiers (`.sm`, `.md` etc.).

As the primeflex css is pretty well written, I extracted the code styles for `.flex-order-x` and repurposed them for cols.

It seems to be working for me other than the fact that the `.sm` modifier is set to `min-width: 576px` when my browser goes down to `520px`. I've modified mine to reflect that but left it at 576 in this example so it works with the breakpoints defined by primeflex.

```css
// Helper classes for reordering columns in grid
.col-order-0 {
    order: 0 !important;
}

.col-order-1 {
    order: 1 !important;
}

.col-order-2 {
    order: 2 !important;
}

.col-order-3 {
    order: 3 !important;
}

.col-order-4 {
    order: 4 !important;
}

.col-order-5 {
    order: 5 !important;
}

.col-order-6 {
    order: 6 !important;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
    .sm\:col-order-0 {
        order: 0 !important;
    }
    .sm\:col-order-1 {
        order: 1 !important;
    }
    .sm\:col-order-2 {
        order: 2 !important;
    }
    .sm\:col-order-3 {
        order: 3 !important;
    }
    .sm\:col-order-4 {
        order: 4 !important;
    }
    .sm\:col-order-5 {
        order: 5 !important;
    }
    .sm\:col-order-6 {
        order: 6 !important;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .md\:col-order-0 {
        order: 0 !important;
    }
    .md\:col-order-1 {
        order: 1 !important;
    }
    .md\:col-order-2 {
        order: 2 !important;
    }
    .md\:col-order-3 {
        order: 3 !important;
    }
    .md\:col-order-4 {
        order: 4 !important;
    }
    .md\:col-order-5 {
        order: 5 !important;
    }
    .md\:col-order-6 {
        order: 6 !important;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .lg\:col-order-0 {
        order: 0 !important;
    }
    .lg\:col-order-1 {
        order: 1 !important;
    }
    .lg\:col-order-2 {
        order: 2 !important;
    }
    .lg\:col-order-3 {
        order: 3 !important;
    }
    .lg\:col-order-4 {
        order: 4 !important;
    }
    .lg\:col-order-5 {
        order: 5 !important;
    }
    .lg\:col-order-6 {
        order: 6 !important;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .xl\:col-order-0 {
        order: 0 !important;
    }
    .xl\:col-order-1 {
        order: 1 !important;
    }
    .xl\:col-order-2 {
        order: 2 !important;
    }
    .xl\:col-order-3 {
        order: 3 !important;
    }
    .xl\:col-order-4 {
        order: 4 !important;
    }
    .xl\:col-order-5 {
        order: 5 !important;
    }
    .xl\:col-order-6 {
        order: 6 !important;
    }
}
```

If using a theme, you can add this to the sass imports and it should just work.

You can then define a grid with columns like this:

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-12 col-order-1 md:col-6 md:col-order-0">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-order-0 md:col-6 md:col-order-1">
  </div>
</div>
```